# Remove last repetitive characters of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say we have a String like these ones :

```
"abcdaaaaefghaaaaaaaaa"
"012003400000000"
```

I would like to remove the last repetitive characters, to obtain this :

```
"abcdaaaaefgh"
"0120034"
```

Is there a simple way to do this, with regex ?
I am kind of having hard times with this and my code begin to look like a gigantic monster...

Some clarification :

- *What is considered as repetitive ?*

  A sequence of at least **2** characters at the end. One character is not considered as repeated. For instance : in `"aaaa"`, `'a'` is not considered as repetitive, but in `"baaaa"`, it is. So in the case of `"aaaa"`, we don't have to change anything to the String. Another instance : `"baa"` must give `"b"`.
- *And for Strings of only one character ?*

  A string like `"a"`in which we only have the char `'a'` must be returned without changing anything, i.e. we must return `"a"`.

Comment: Only one character is repeated?

Comment: Is the last character always repeated?

Comment: No, the last character is not always repeated. It can have a sequence of at least 2 characters at the end. One character is not considered as repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use a regex:

```
public class Test {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println(removeTrailingDupes("abcdaaaaefghaaaaaaaaa"));
    System.out.println(removeTrailingDupes("012003400000000"));
    System.out.println(removeTrailingDupes("0120034000000001"));
    System.out.println(removeTrailingDupes("cc"));
    System.out.println(removeTrailingDupes("c"));
  }

  private String removeTrailingDupes(String s) {
    // Is there a dupe?
    int l = s.length();
    if (l > 1 && s.charAt(l - 1) == s.charAt(l - 2)) {
      // Where to cut.
      int cut = l - 2;
      // What to cut.
      char c = s.charAt(cut);
      while (cut > 0 && s.charAt(cut - 1) == c) {
        // Cut that one too.
        cut -= 1;
      }
      // Cut off the repeats.
      return s.substring(0, cut);
    }
    // Return it untouched.
    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

To match @JonSkeet's "spec":

Note that this will *only* remove characters that are *duplicated* at the end. That means single character strings will not be touched but two-character strings could become empty if both characters are the same:

```
"" => ""
"x" => "x"
"xx" => ""
"aaaa" => ""
"ax" => "ax"
"abcd" => "abcd"
"abcdddd" => "abc"
```

I wonder if it would be possible to achieve that level of control in a regex?

**Added** as a result of the *... but If we use this regex with aaaa for example, it returns nothing. It should return aaaa.* comment:

Instead, use:

```
  private String removeTrailingDupes(String s) {
    // Is there a dupe?
    int l = s.length();
    if (l > 1 && s.charAt(l - 1) == s.charAt(l - 2)) {
      // Where to cut.
      int cut = l - 2;
      // What to cut.
      char c = s.charAt(cut);
      while (cut > 0 && s.charAt(cut - 1) == c) {
        // Cut that one too.
        cut -= 1;
      }
      // Cut off the repeats.
      return cut > 0 ? s.substring(0, cut): s;
    }
    // Return it untouched.
    return s;
  }
```

which has the contract:

```
"" => ""
"x" => "x"
"xx" => "xx"
"aaaa" => "aaaa"
"ax" => "ax"
"abcd" => "abcd"
"abcdddd" => "abc"
```

Comment: I accept your answer ! Your edit does exactly what I want, and does not look like my horrible monster code, thank you !

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) together with a back reference:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+$", "");
```

**EDIT**

To meet the requirement that the entire string can't get removed I would simply add a check afterwards instead of making the regex overly complicated:

```
public String replaceLastRepeated(String str) {
    String replaced = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+$", "");
    if (replaced.equals("")) {
        return str;
    }
    return replaced;
}
```

Comment: damn it! I was writing the same thing :)

Comment: @Eugene not only you, anyway +1 for the fastest gun.

Comment: If we use this regex with `aaaa` for example, it returns nothing. It should return `aaaa`

Comment: @Pigrou: In that case you need to refine your specifications. In what cases should the last characters not be removed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I'd use a regex for this:

```
public static String removeRepeatedLastCharacter(String text) {
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        return text;
    }
    char lastCharacter = text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
    // Look backwards through the string until you find anything which isn't
    // the final character
    for (int i = text.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (text.charAt(i) != lastCharacter) {
            // Add one to *include* index i
            return text.substring(0, i + 1);
        }
    }
    // Looks like we had a string such as "1111111111111".
    return "";
}
```

*Personally* I find that easier to understand than a regex. It may or may not be faster - I wouldn't like to make a prediction.

Note that this will *always* remove the final character, whether it's repeated or not. That means single character strings will always end up as empty strings:

```
"" => ""
"x" => ""
"xx" => ""
"ax" => "a"
"abcd" => "abc"
"abcdddd" => "abc"
```

Comment: Not sure if you've correctly handled the one-character case and the two-character case correctly. Test with "c" and with "0120034000000001" to confirm.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: A single character will end up returning an empty string, always. Two characters should be okay - it'll enter the for loop once (`i == 0`) and will return `text.substring(0, 1)` if the two characters are different.

Comment: Sorry - I edited my comment. We seem to disagree on interpretation. No problem

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Yup, both behaved as I expected them to. Definitely a matter of the OP not being precise. I'll explain the behaviour in my answer.

Comment: I like the fact that is does not use regex, but If we use this regex with `aaaa` for example, it returns nothing. It should return `aaaa`.

Comment: I edited my question to be clear, maybe if you have ideas you can adapt your answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(.)\1+$` by an empty string:

```java
"abcddddd".replaceFirst("(.)\\1+$", ""); // returns abc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
public class Remover {
     public static String removeTrailing(String toProcess)
     {
        char lastOne = toProcess.charAt(toProcess.length() - 1);
        return toProcess.replaceAll(lastOne + "+$", "");
     } 

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        String test1 = "abcdaaaaefghaaaaaaaaa";
        String test2 = "012003400000000";

        System.out.println("Test1 without trail : " + removeTrailing(test1));
        System.out.println("Test2 without trail : " + removeTrailing(test2));
     }
}
```